# Open a Word Doc from Excel using VBA to find a Date text and replace it with a date text from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a word doc with text and there is also a date text in there showing this format:

```
text text text 17.01.2020 text text text.
```

I want to replace the above date text with a cell from Excel that is also a date looking like this 18.01.2020.

So the VBA code should do the following:

1.Open word doc

2.find the text and replace it with the one from Excel

3.save Word doc.

```
Sub DocSearchandReplace()
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\sampletest.docx")
With wdDoc.Content.Find
  .Date = "???"
  .Replacement.Cell = "referencing a cell from Excel??"
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

wdDoc.Save 'it however always prompt a word warning, how to surpress it?
wdDoc.Close 'it only closes the doc inside Word without closing the whole program.

Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am not sure what to write in the .Date and .Replacement.Cell sections.

Comment: *"Can someone help implement the above steps using VBA?"* is actually exactly the case that is not a real question (see the link in my comment above). Also just saying *"it is not working"* is not an error description. •  Instead please describe what's wrong with your code, what is working already and where do you get errors? What does your code versus what did you expect? At which part did you exactly got stuck? Where in your code is the issue that stops you from implementing it? • Also I think a `.Date = "???"` does not exist in `.Content.Find`

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to write it. I used ??? to show that I don't know what to write. I really don't know how much more obvious you want me to show that I am lost in that part. Hopefully my edit works this time? I appreciate your suggestion, but I've asked questions like this without any issue. I think I am precise enough. If you don't know the answer, that's fine. Please let others answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your syntax is wrong. `.Date` and `.Replacement.Cell` properties don't exist in the `Find` object. Make sure to read the manual of the [find object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find) and don't invent properties.

The correct syntac according to  [Finding and Replacing Text or Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting) is something like:

```
With wdDoc.Content.Find 
    .ClearFormatting 
    .Text = "17.01.2020" 'your date to replace
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting 
    .Replacement.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text 'read value from sheet1 cell A1
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue 
End With
```

---

According to Cindys comment there exist wildcards matching in Word that is similar to using regular expressions.

```
With wdDoc.Content.Find 
    .ClearFormatting 
    .Text = "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}"  'will match ##.##.####
    .MatchWildcards = True 'makes sure the above wildcards are recognized
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting 
    .Replacement.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text 'read value from sheet1 cell A1
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue 
End With
```

Since you are using late binding you must either define your Word constants for the [WdFindWrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfindwrap) and [WdReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreplace) enumeration before using them

```
Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2
Const wdFindContinue As Long = 1
```

or replace them by their values

```
.Execute Replace:=2, Forward:=True, Wrap:=1
```

or set a reference to Word and use eary binding so they are defined automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Peh .Text = "17.01.2020" the date is not hard coded. It's dynamic. The code should find whatever that date is using that format and replace it. That's why I didn't use .TEXT.

Comment: Well you can obviously only replace what you know. If you don't know that date to replace you cannot search for it. Then you need to find a pattern which is something different and you must use Regular Expressions for that (which Word does not support out of the box). See [Is there a way to search for a pattern in a MS Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/846646/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-a-pattern-in-a-ms-word-document).

Comment: So you're saying that Word VBA can't find a text string using this format dd.mm.yyyy? Ok, then this code is not a fit for this purpose.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks a lot. I didn't forget you. I'll let you know, once I've checked the code. Thanks.

Comment: it has a runtime error here Replace:=wdReplaceAll, it says variable not defined. Do you know why?

Comment: @purpleblau yes because you did use late binding `CreateObject("word.application")` and did not set a reference to MS Word you cannot use the [WdReplace Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreplace) in Excel and need to replace it with its values or define them as constants before using `Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2`. See my edit.

Comment: I put the code for saving and closing the word. However, there is always a prompt saying " sure to save the tracked changes". I have to click yes and it only closes the doc and not the entire word program. I tried to use wdApp.close it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @purpleblau yes, please open up a new question for that describe your issue and show the exact code you tried and the error message you got. We cannot handle follow up questions in comments if they are new ones, questions have to be asked as questions.